# KendoUI Grid how to disable only some filters operators

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to disable only some filter (e.g. isnotnull or isnull) globally on all my grids, without redefine all operators that I want to preserve. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can globaly set to undefined the filter you want to hide, like this:

```
kendo.ui.FilterMenu.fn.options.operators.number.isnotnull = undefined;
kendo.ui.FilterMenu.fn.options.operators.string.isnotnull = undefined;
kendo.ui.FilterMenu.fn.options.operators.date.isnotnull = undefined;
kendo.ui.FilterMenu.fn.options.operators.enums.isnotnull = undefined;
```